# How can I wrap up multiple components (WebElements) to a single one? Componet Object Model and Page Object Model

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, page-factory

I am developing tests for a Angular.io based web application. I am writing in Java and I am using Selenium (WebDriver). I follow the Page Object Model using the PageFactory class by Selenium. Since I have some really complex and nested pages, I would like to get certain componets (like a nedted div) from a page and wrap it in a single WebElement / custom object. I think this is called Component Object Pattern.

Let's keep it simple and generic. Let's say I have this html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="list">
          <div class="element">
              <div class="country">France</div>
              <div class="capital">Paris</div>
          </div>
          <div class="element">
              <div class="country">Norway</div>
              <div class="capital">Oslo</div>
          </div>
          <div class="element">
              <div class="country">United Kingdom</div>
              <div class="capital">London</div>
          </div>
          <!-- ... -->
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Following the Page Object Pattern and using the Pagefactory class provided by Selenium, I have this class representing the page:

```
import thisClass;
import thatClass;

public class ListPage {
    ChromeDriver driver;
    
    public ListPage(ChromeDriver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @FindAll(@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//div[@class = 'element']"))
    private List<WebElement> elements;

    @FindAll(@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//div[@class = 'country']"))
    private List<WebElement> countrys;

    @FindAll(@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//div[@class = 'capital']"))
    private List<WebElement> capitals;
}
```

Is there a way I can define the class "Element", for example:

```
class Element {
    public WebElement country;
    public WebElement capital;

    Element(WebElement country, WebElement capital) {
        this.country = country;
        this.capital = capital;
    }
}
```

and convert `private List<WebElement> elements;` to `private List<Element> elements;` so I can obmit "countrys" and "capitals"? This ways I would have to call `elements.get(index).country.getText()` or something.

It would help me alot, if this would be possible.

Comment: It seems like you could do this, but not sure why... why not create a class with strings as properties?  WebElement references are not a good way to store data since they have a limited period of time when they are not "stale".  So any info you want to retain should be received by using a method on them at the time they are available.  The "Page" object is a name only, so you could create a "Page" object of "ThisPageElement" which stores string of country, string of capital, etc...  Change your architecture to meet it's function.

Comment: in the structure you post above you might just use findElements() to get the elements... then iterate over that list and use element.findElement() to get each piece of data.  Each webelement has it's own findElement() method within it's scope in the node.

Comment: Just for your exploration, I have created something that allows to create components. Take a look if it's applicable to your situation: [Metalloid](https://github.com/Rafal-Laskowski/Metalloid-Page-Factory). You might be interested in this part of the documentation: [Components](https://github.com/Rafal-Laskowski/Metalloid-Page-Factory/wiki/3.-Injectable-Components)